# Demand curve confusion

Tags: mathematical-economics

My economics textbook says that demand curves slope downward - but then goes on to say that when demand increases, prices go up! Does anyone else find this confusing?

Comment: Does your textbook explain what it means by "demand increases"?  Is that a movement along the demand curve, or is it a shift of the whole curve?

Answer (score 5):

Separate the concepts "an increase in quantity demanded" from "shifting of the demand schedule".

The second means that for some reason, say change in tastes, preferences, *the whole demand curve shifts*: now, *quantity demanded* for the product has increased for all price levels, compared to the previous situation, but of course  the downward slope remains.

Your economics textbook should have said

> "Demand curves slope downward - but when demand increases (*in the
>   sense of shifting the whole demand curve due to, say, a change in
>   consumer preferences*), *equilibrium* price goes up".

Comment: +1 for clearing up this very common confusion both in textbooks and students

Answer (score 3):

The book probably intends you to think like this

[image]

so you have a downward-sloping demand curve (lower prices lead to higher demand), but if demand increases for a reason not related to price (a shift from the *Demand 1* curve to the *Demand 2* curve) then the new equilibrium on the upward-sloping supply curve will be at a higher price and quantity

There are a lot of implicit assumptions here, especially

- the direction of the slope of the supply curve
- whatever changed the demand curve did not affect the supply curve

Comment: This is exactly the confusion in the book. On the one hand, you are saying that 'lower prices lead to higher demand'. On the other hand, you draw a picture (much like the picture in my textbook) showing the opposite.